# What are the differences in coding a destruction algorithm for destroying double and singly linked lists separately in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

In my exam there was a question like this and I've been thinking that what are the differences in coding a destruction algorithm for destroying double and singly linked lists separately in C?

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say I see no need for any difference. An algorithm that works on a singly-linked list (iterating from head to tail) will work just as well on a doubly-linked list. I suppose you can destroy a doubly-linked list starting from any node, but that's bad design.

Comment: Is the double linked list circular (the tail pointing at the head)? If so (and it usually is), you might have to implement a different conditional on the loop.

Comment: @Beta - often enough, the "head" of a doubly linked list will be associated with a different data structure or memory model... moreover, if you're going to iterate until you hit `NULL`, now you might need to iterate until you (re)hit `head`.

Comment: @Myst: Exactly the same caveat applies to a circular *singly* linked list.

Comment: @Beta - In a **singly** linked list, `head != tail` (the tail is often `NULL`)... whereas in a **doubly** linked list, `head == tail`, which could result in a double `free` unless you test for it.

Comment: @Myst: Forgive me, but you're wrong. In a circular linked list, whether singly- or doubly-linked, it makes no sense to have `head == tail`; there's no point in having `tail` in that case. But if you want to have it, fine, and your destruction algorithm must take that into account; it makes **no difference** whether the list is singly- or doubly-linked.

Comment: @Beta - it is the nature of singly linked lists that they are usually used as "stack" style data structure (LIFO / FIFO). They are, by nature, almost always non-circular. In contrast, the purpose of a doubly linked list is to allow easy insertion and removal of nodes in the middle of the list. They are, by nature, almost always circular. but, as you wish.

Answer (score -1):

If your data type allows your doubly-linked list to be a ring, you need to break the link back to the head.  Then traverse the list as usual, copying pointers and freeing as you go.

Comment: Why must you break the back link in the head? What happens if you don't? Is it *nothing?*

Comment: Thanks for your question.  My answer was poorly-worded I should have said to break the link back TO the head.

Remember, in a ring, if you don't figure out some way to stop from going around the circle that you will eventually hit the same node twice. In that case, you could follow corrupted pointers or even worse -- free() memory that has already been free()d.  This last situation basically opens the gates to Hell and lets all the daemons out.